# Visual Studio SQL Project failing to change Filestream column to allow NULLs

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

I am using a SQL Project in Visual Studio (SSDT) and I have a column defined as:

```
BinaryDocument VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM NOT NULL
```

I need to make a change to allow NULL, so I changed the definition to:

```
BinaryDocument VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM NULL
```

But when publish the project, the script generated shows:

```
ALTER TABLE [Docs] ALTER COLUMN [BinaryDocument] VARBINARY (MAX) NULL;
```

Which, as you would expect because you can't remove FILESTREAM from a column, gives the following error:

> Cannot alter column 'BinaryDocument' in table 'Docs' to add or remove the FILESTREAM column attribute.

**Does anyone know if this is supposed to work or is it just me? Is there any workaround?**

EDIT

It's not just restricted to making NULLable.  Tried setting a default and same problem:

```
BinaryDocument VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM NOT NULL DEFAULT(0x00)
```

Yields the same output in the publish script as above:

```
ALTER TABLE [Docs] ALTER COLUMN [BinaryDocument] VARBINARY (MAX) NOT NULL;
```

So it seems to honour the NULL/NOT NULL changes, but fails to carry the FILESTREAM keyword into the output script :(

Comment: Logged it as a Connect bug https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1268660

Comment: I get the same error when publishing via the sqlpackage.exe command line tool. However, when I publish via Visual Studio, it works for me. I'm wondering if I'm using a different version of SSDT within VS than you. In VS Help about, it is reporting SSDT version 12.0.50730.0

Comment: BTW, I asked a similar question before seeing yours. Sadly no one has replied to mine either yet but in case I get a response and you don't the link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869927/sqlpackage-breaks-when-trying-to-alter-a-filestream-column

Comment: @SimonGreen See connect bug in my comment above. They have confirmed it: "Thank you for your feedback. The issue has been confirmed as a product defect. We have a fix and will deliver the fix in a SSDT release soon."

Comment: Yes - thanks. I was using a slightly older sqlpackage.exe. Getting the latest from the VS SSDT package (sqlspackage.exe version 12.0.3021.0) fixed the issue