# sqlpackage breaks when trying to alter a FILESTREAM column

Tags: dacpac, dac, sqlpackage

I have a SQL Database project, where I have recently amended a `FILESTREAM` column to allow nulls. I am trying to publish the project's dacpac to a db where the column already exists, as a filestream column, but is currently `NOT NULL`.

I am performing the publish using the sqlpackage.exe command line tool (version 12.0.2882.1). However, it produces the error:

```
Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 4990, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot alter column 'document' in table 'Document' to add or remove the FILESTREAM column attribute.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Document] ALTER COLUMN [document] VARBINARY (MAX) NULL;
```

The sql in the error looks like the generated script is trying to remove the FILESTREAM attribute on the column, which I guess is why SQL Server is complaining... but why is it doing this? My DB project still has the column marked as `FILESTREAM`

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by upgrading sqlpackage.exe and associated libraries from version 12.0.2882.1 to  12.0.3021.1